# How do I use a local image on a discord.js rich embed?

Tags: discord.js

I have this code:

```
var datos = ["dato1","dato2","dato3"]

console.log ("》" + message.author.username + " introdujo el comando:  " + message.content + "  en  " + message.guild.name);

let embed = new discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle("Datos sobre gatos  ")

    .setColor(12118406)
    .setDescription(datos[Math.floor(Math.random() * datos.length)])
    .setFooter("© 2018 República Gamer LLC", bot.user.avatarURL)
    .setImage("http://i.imgur.com/sYyH2IM.png")
message.channel.send({embed})

.catch ((err) => {
    console.error(err);

    let embed = new discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor(15806281)
        .setTitle("❌ Ocurrió un error")
        .setDescription("Ocurrió un error durante la ejecución del comando")
    message.channel.send({embed})
})
```

How can I use a local image path in place of a URL (on the .setImage() line)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In [discord.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js) v13 and on, `MessageEmbed#attachFiles` has been [deprecated](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#customizable-manager-caches). You should directly add the files into the response from now on.

> MessageEmbed#attachFiles has been removed; files should now be
> attached directly to the message instead of the embed.

```
// Before v13
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle('Attachments').attachFiles(['./image1.png', './image2.jpg']);
channel.send(embed);
// v13
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle('Attachment').setImage('attachment://image.png');
channel.send({ embeds: [embed], files: ['./image.png'] });
```

Answer (score 17):

Updated Luke's code to Discord.js v12 for anyone else in 2020 who has this same problem

```
const attachment = new Discord
                      .MessageAttachment('./card_images/sample.png', 'sample.png');
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .setTitle('Wicked Sweet Title')
     .attachFiles(attachment)
     .setImage('attachment://sample.png');

message.channel.send({embed});
```

Comment: Use the edit button to edit an answer.

Answer (score 8):

This works for me.

```
const attachment = new Discord.Attachment('./card_images/sample.png', 'sample.png');
const embed = new RichEmbed()
        .setTitle('Wicked Sweet Title')
        .attachFile(attachment)
        .setImage('attachment://sample.png');
message.channel.send({embed}).catch(console.error)
```

Answer (score 3):

The other way to do it would be:

```js
const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment('./help.png', 'help.png');

message.channel.send({
  embed: {
    files: [
      attachment
    ],
    image: {
      url: 'attachment://help.png'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: But on this way you aren't using Rich Embeds

Comment: Rich Embeds are now MessageEmbeds in v12 and this method is also a MessageEmbed just a different method to do the same thing. You can add fields and everything else in this format as well from the documentation

Answer (score 0):

We wave a new way to make this on D.js v14

```
const attachment = new AttachmentBuilder('./image.png', { name: 'image1.png' });
const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setTitle('Attachments')
  .setImage(`attachment://${attachment.name}`);

channel.send({
  embeds: [embed],
  files: [attachment]
});
```

Answer (score -10):

**Hello! Unfortunately, Discord's API only accepts URLs and not local paths.**

You can only upload your images to a server/image hosting website and get the URL.