# How do you attach local files to an embed?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const {Client, MessageAttachment} = require('discord.js');
const bot3 = new Client();


const mark2 = '*info personal'
const mark3 = '*info guild'
const mark4 = '*info roles'
bot3.on('message', msg =>{

    if (msg.content.startsWith(mark2)){
        const hashitag = msg.author.id
        const actualhashitag = msg.author.discriminator
        const evenbetterhashitag = "#" + actualhashitag 
        const personalembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Stuff about you')
            .setImage(msg.author.displayAvatarURL())
            .setColor('#D11111')
            .addField('Your username',  msg.author.username)
            .addField('Your hashtag', hashitag, true)
            .addField('Your actual hashtag', actualhashitag, true)
            .addField('Your even realer hashtag', evenbetterhashitag, true)   
            .addField('Your amount of friends', 'Discord bots can not know that sadly')
            .addField('Your role', msg.member.roles.cache.map(role => role.name).join(", ") )
            .addField('Your role id', msg.member.roles.cache.map(role => role.id).join(", ") )
            .addField('Your nickname', msg.member.nickname);
        msg.channel.send(personalembed)
    }
    if (msg.content.startsWith(mark3)){




        const guildembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

            .setTitle(msg.guild.name)
            .setImage(msg.guild.iconURL())
            .setColor('#97FF00')
            .addField('the id of the server', msg.guild.id)
            .addField('the owner', msg.guild.owner.user.username)
            .addField('the owner tag', msg.guild.owner.user.tag)
            .addField('the owner id', msg.guild.ownerID)
            .addField('the owner nickname', msg.guild.owner.nickname)
            .addField('all roles', msg.guild.roles.cache.map(role => role.name).join(", ") ) 
            .addField('the bots', msg.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.bot).map(member => member.user.tag).join(' | '))
            .addField('the bots actual name', msg.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.bot).map(member => member.user.username).join(' | '))
            .addField('the bot ids', msg.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.bot).map(member => member.user.id).join(' | '))
            .addField('the bots hashtag(without the hashtag)', msg.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.bot).map(member => member.user.discriminator).join(' | '))
        msg.channel.send(guildembed)

    }  

    if(msg.content.startsWith(mark4)){
        const attachmento = new MessageAttachment('./stuff\role5.png', 'name') 
        const roleembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('All roles and the people with the roles')
            .attachFiles(attachmento)
            .setThumbnail(attachmento)
            .setColor('FFA737')
        msg.channel.send(roleembed)
    }


})

bot3.login(process.env.token3)
```

The discord.js version is 12.2.0 if you're wondering.
I want to attach an image to the third embed(Ignore the title of the embed I'll try deal with that later) It is a local file called role5. I can't seem to be able to attach that file to the embed though. This is what happens.

```
2020-06-17T11:33:33.792109+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-06-17T11:33:34.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-06-17T11:33:35.043286+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-06-17T11:33:35.136963+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: Process exited with status 143
2020-06-17T11:33:35.621163+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2020-06-17T11:33:36.314618+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-06-17T11:33:38.193183+00:00 app[Worker.1]: This bot is online
2020-06-17T11:34:17.887173+00:00 app[Worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/stuff
2020-06-17T11:34:17.887251+00:00 app[Worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
2020-06-17T11:34:17.887307+00:00 app[Worker.1]: (node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use a local image on a discord.js rich embed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51199950/90527)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=attachFiles), when creating an embed, you need to use `.attachFiles()` to attach the local file to the embed. After that you can use `attachment://fileName.extension` when setting an embed image/icons.

Example with the role embed:

```
const roleembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('All roles and the people with the roles')
            .attachFiles('./stuff/role5.png')
            .setThumbnail("attachment://role5.png")
            .setColor('FFA737')
        msg.channel.send(roleembed)
```

Comment: Oh that's what i was doing wrong. I didn't need the part before. Ok. makes sense.

Comment: Another question though. Is there anyway of making the thumbnail bigger so it's more easily visible. I know using setImage instead of setThumbnail would make it bigger but I want it in the start not the end.