# Not able to display local Image in embed? Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I've tried many ways to get photos working in embeds but I cant. It always just doesn't show an image and I don't know why.

I have a function that generates a random name and then saves a file to a folder called "Images"
then I try to display that image using a path in a embed but it doesn't work.
Alot of code is removed so its easier to work with.

```
var RandomId = "Images/" + MakeId(16) + ".png"
var FileName = RandomId.replace("Images/", "")

//writefile stuff here that makes file

const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(RandomId , FileName);
const ExampleCommand = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .setColor("#21BA45")
    .setTitle(CommandTitle.content)
    .setDescription(CommandDescription.content)
    .addField(CommandMediaDescription, "-")
    .setImage("attachment://" + FileName)
Channel.send(ExampleCommand)
```

Image to show that it gets created and saved

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use a local image on a discord.js rich embed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51199950/90527)

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using PascalCase in javascript unless for classes because it gives confusing for yourself and other devs, as the sytnax highlighting shows,

Anyways the issue is that you aren't attaching the attachment:

```js
ExampleCommand
   .attachFiles(attachment)
   .setColor("#21BA45")
   .setTitle(CommandTitle.content)
   .setDescription(CommandDescription.content)
   .addField(CommandMediaDescription, "-")
   .setImage("attachment://" + FileName);
```