# DIscord.js putting an attachment in an embed's thumbnail doesn't show up

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm using discord.js and i'm trying to a local image show up in the embed's thumbnail however it doesn't show up at all and the thumbnail is empty without sending any errors

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(`${user.tag}\'s profile (${user.id})`, user.avatarURL())
        .addField(`Skin`, `${skin2}`)
        .addField(`Total Coins`, `${coinicon} ${coins}`)
        .addField(`Inventory Items (${amount})`, `${items}`)
        .setThumbnail('attachment://red.png')
        .setTimestamp()
        .setColor('#00ffff')
        .setFooter(message.member.user.tag, message.author.avatarURL());
        message.channel.send(embed)
```

the "red.png" is stored like this

[image: image's path]

i also tried changing the code to

```js
.setThumbnail('attachment://assets//colors//red.png')
```

but it didn't work either, any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use a local image on a discord.js rich embed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51199950/90527)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In oder to set `attachment://red.png`, you actually need to attach it first. 
To do that, create an attachment with the local path + the name of the attachment (which will be used in `attachment://`):

```js
const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(
    "./path/to/red.png", // <- local image path
    "red.png"            // <- name for "attachment://"
);
```

Then attach it using

```js
.attachFiles(attachment)
```

---

In your code:

```js
const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment("./path/to/red.png", "red.png");

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .attachFiles(attachment) // <- add attachment
    .setAuthor(`${user.tag}\'s profile (${user.id})`, user.avatarURL())
    .addField(`Skin`, `${skin2}`)
    .addField(`Total Coins`, `${coinicon} ${coins}`)
    .addField(`Inventory Items (${amount})`, `${items}`)
    .setThumbnail('attachment://red.png')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setColor('#00ffff')
    .setFooter(message.member.user.tag, message.author.avatarURL());

message.channel.send(embed);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the first code in your post, try to change message.channel.send to:

```js
message.channel.send({
    embed,
    files: [{
        attachment: '../../assets/colors/red.png',
        name: 'red.png'
    }]
});
```