# How can I use a local image as thumbnail of embed in discord.js v13?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am making a fun discord bot and i wanted to make a character creator. To create the characters, I need to use the jimp node module, that works absolutely perfectly. The problem is that when i try to embed it with
`` .setThumbnail(`images/characters/${interaction.user.id}.png\`) `` i get this error:

```
data.embeds[0].image.url: Scheme "file" is not supported. Scheme must be one of ('http', 'https').
```

Comment: See [attaching images to embeds](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#attaching-images).

Comment: Ohhhh ok i found it. The issue was, that i was using ephemeral messages

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[How do I use a local image on a discord.js rich embed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51199950/90527)", "[DIscord.js putting an attachment in an embed's thumbnail doesn't show up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66692920/90527)"