# Discord.js local image in embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to get this into an embed, there are multiple file types, png, jpg, gif, and so on.

I have tried looking around and can't find a solution

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require("fs")

module.exports = {
    name: 'ari',
    description: "Sends a user his queen",
    
    async execute(message, args) {
        if(message.channel.id === "768497955417096272"){
            fs.readdir('./ariana', (err, files) => {
                if(err) console.error(err);
                const randImage = files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)];
                message.channel.send({
                    files: ["./ariana/"+randImage]
                })
            })
        }else{
            message.channel.send("Go to Pics/Gifs channel!")
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or is just not working?

Comment: My code is working, but I don't know how to embed it. I have read the docs, and looked through this site, but can't seem to find an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use a local image on a discord.js rich embed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51199950/90527)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) to send image from local and using it embed you need to declare attachment and using attachment name and change embed option thumbnail url by using `'attachment://<attachment-name>'`

```js
// Send an embed with a local image inside
channel.send(embed, {
  embed: {
    thumbnail: {
         url: 'attachment://file.jpg'
      }
   },
   files: [{
      attachment: 'entire/path/to/file.jpg',
      name: 'file.jpg'
   }]
})
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

or if you want to using in setImage

```js
      const embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
        .attachFiles([{ name: 'file.jpg', attachment: 'entire/path/to/file.jpg' }])
        .setImage('attachment://file.jpg');
      channel.send(embed);
```